# how to factor a number with more than 600 digits in the most efficent way on a computer?

Tags: factoring

I am wondering, if you can factor a number with more than 600 digits on a computer as fast as possible (if its even working). With efficient I mean like 6 hours. Best regards

Comment: "*As of 2019, the largest factored RSA number was 795 bits long (240 decimal digits, see RSA-240). Its factorization, by a state-of-the-art distributed implementation, took around 900 CPU years. No larger RSA key is known publicly to have been factored. In practice, RSA keys are typically 1024 to 4096 bits long.*"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: Ok, question answered. :)